# Add CSS to individual tab in tab panel Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to change the color of a tab in a tabpanel I have when my app goes online or offline. I have the online and offline events already setup but now I need to be able to change the color of the tab from these events.

How do I go about accessing an individual tab and setting it's CSS?

Answer (score 0):

you could use ext component query to get the handle of the component and then add/remove class

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('yourselector')[0].addCls('yourclass')
```

Comment: Is there a `removeCls` function?

Comment: Yes removeCls and addCls are methods of all components that inherits from [Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the individual tab from tabpanel by referring it as following inside the controller class (inside the refs):

```
myDesiredTab: '#myTabPanelId container[title=myDesiredTabTitle]'
```

and afterward you can try:

```
this.getMyDesiredTab().tab.setCls('myDesiredCssClass');
```

This idea hasn't been tested but might just work as the tabbar does have cls config and we have a way to access the individual tab.